# Simulate an UPDATE/DELETE query before execution

Tags: php, sql, mysql

For a very sensitive system, I want to be sure that the queries being executed do the job they are intended to do and nothing more. I have a tool that allows me to insert SQL statements and have them later executed via a cron job after being approved by an administrator. But to make sure that the queries don't destroy the entire database, I want to activate a simulation process where I want to check how many rows the UPDATE or DELETE statement would affect.

I'm thinking of somehow replacing "UPDATE" and "DELETE" with "SELECT count(*)" with the given statements so that I can get the rows that might be affected. Am I thinking very simply or am I missing some details? Maybe there is a library in PHP that I can use for this process?

Comment: It's pretty common to `select` the affected rows prior to converting the query to an `update/delete`

Comment: Or make backup of data before delete/update (for a rollback or revert)

Comment: Wrap it in a transaction and roll it back afterwards. Run it on a recent copy of the real database. Or use a SELECT as above

Comment: Well, i think what you mean by `"SELECT count(*)"` is by logging, correct? Generally that's the way to go around with cron jobs is to log certain important steps taking place during the process and preferably to a separate file. Unfortunately there isn't any library which will help you in this case since it's purely based on how one handle all edge cases and perform the perfect transaction.

Comment: If the data is that sensitive, the idea of running raw SQL statements against the database sounds risky.  Surely this would be better dealt with by using code which can be tested and proved to work properly rather than ad hoc SQL.

Comment: Yeah, this is true. But yes, the sql runs on the prod data and thats why I am thinking for a system to prevent problems. Transaction is one of the solutions but I am bit afraid, not that something went wrong with the rollback, then I have more problems.

Answer (score 1):

This is easily achievable using `START TRANSACTION;` before your query and `ROLLBACK;` right after. You can determine exactly what was affected without committing the changes.

This is how phpMyAdmin "simulates" its queries.

Comment: While possible, this might not be preferable on a production system where your transaction holds up other concurrent processes while you evaluate if it was successful or not.

Comment: @Stu OP said they wanted to be sure - this is the best way to do so. Alternative methods such as `SELECT` queries will not be accurate as they will not invoke triggers or cascade deletes.

Comment: Thanks @jhmckimm . Yes, this is something I am thinking for, also. I am only scared if something happens with the rollback. I will try different options and see what fits for our case.

Comment: @Mutatos I am curious what approach you settled on, if one at all? :)